# Play a sound by clicking a button

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having issues on running a code, that is to run a sound by clicking button in android studio using kotlin.

the XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gun"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="130dp"
        android:text="gun" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Kotlin Code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val buttonomega = findViewById<View>(R.id.gun) as Button
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gunfire)
        val playBlownose = findViewById<View>(R.id.gun)

 buttonomega.setOnClickListener{

        }
```

NOTE: the kotlin Code is incomplete because after i tried a lot i wasn't able to do it. if you were able to do it, can you tell me how you did it.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play sound like this:

```kotlin
gun.setOnClickListener {
   var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sample_media)
   mediaPlayer?.start()
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to implement the button like this

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gunfire)
        val playBlownose = findViewById<View>(R.id.)

 gun.setOnClickListener{
// do your work here
        }
```